# Induction Proof on Integration by part

Tags: integration, induction

I am trying to prove that by Mathematical Induction :

$$\sin(x)= \int_{0}^{x} \cos(t) dt $$ 
$$= x cos(x)+\frac{x^{2}}{2} \sin(x)- \frac{x^{3}}{3!} \cos(x)- \frac{x^{4}}{4!} \sin(x)+\frac{x^{5}}{5!} \sin(x).........$$
$$ = cos(x) \bigg(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}....\bigg)+sin(x) \bigg(x-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}....\bigg)$$
$$ = cos(x) \bigg(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}....\bigg)-sin(x) \bigg(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}....\bigg)+sin(x)$$

So what I have done so far, that I have integrated by parts several time, but what I do not understand how induction work on integration, like what is my base case and what is my inductive step.

$$\int_{0}^{x} \cos(t) dt $$
Let $$u= cos(t)$$ and $$du = -sin(t) dt $$ Then, let $$ dv= dt$$ and $$v=t$$

Then we have, 
$$\int_{0}^{x} \cos(t) dt = t cos(t) \mid_{0}^{x}+ \int_{0}^{x} tsin(t) dt$$ 
$$= x cos(x) + \int_{0}^{x} tsin(t) dt$$

Then I consider $$  \int_{0}^{x} tsin(t) dt$$ 
I let $$ s=sin(t)$$ and $$ ds=cos(t) dt$$ Then $$dr=t$$ $$ r=\frac{t^2}{2}$$

So, 
$$\int_{0}^{x} tsin(t) dt= \frac{t^2sin(t)}{2} \mid_{0}^{x} - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x} t^{2}cos(t) dt$$
Which is $$\int_{0}^{x} tsin(t) dt= \frac{x^2sin(x)}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x} t^{2}cos(t) dt$$

Comment: Induction... on what?

Comment: If $\sin x$ is defined as $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and $\cos x$ is defined as $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ they both are entire functions and termwise integration is allowed, trivially leading to $\int_{0}^{x}\cos(t)\,dt = \sin(t)$.